# Appending in front vs back of a string in C++

Tags: c++, string

In C++ vectors `push_back()` takes constant time, where as `push_front()` takes linear time.
In regards to that I have some confusion regarding strings.

let string `a` be of length `n` and string `b` be of length m. Then **what will be the time complexity of following operations :**

1. `a += b`
2. `a = b + a`
3. `a += 'x'`
4. `a = 'x' + a`

according to my undersanding `1` and `3` should have constant time complexity.

Comment: 1. depends on the length of `b`. 2. depends on the length of `a` and `b`. 3. is O(1) (like `push_back()`). 4. depends on the length of `a`.

Comment: Remarkably, [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) denotes, that there are no complexity guarantees by standard but refers to [std::vector::insert()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...this seems to have a few problems.

`std::vector` has a `push_back` (which has amortized constant complexity), but doesn't have a `push_front` at all. `std::list` and `std::deque` both provide `push_front`, but for them it's constant complexity. You can add an item at the beginning of a `vector` using `insert`, which does have linear complexity though.

Getting to your individual examples (all relating to `string`s, not `vector`s):

#### `a += b`

I'd normally expect this to be O(m). C++ guarantees that strings are contiguous, so we need to copy the contents of `b` to the end of the previous contents of `a`.

If the string has to be reallocated, I'd expect to see amortized constant complexity, much like `vector` guarantees, but to the best of my recollection `std::string` doesn't actually require it.

#### `a = b + a`

I'd expect this to be O(n + m). It basically creates a new (temporary) string  holding the contents of `b` followed by the contents of `a`, then assigns that temporary to `a`.

#### `a += 'a'`

I'd expect this to have amortized constant complexity, but (as outlined above) I don't believe it's guaranteed.

#### `a = 'x' + a`

I'd expect this to be linear on the length of `a`.